# Which one is correct? affect or effect

Tags: grammar

what should I write
The complicated political situation will affect/effect our timeline?
Please help me.

Comment: Have you used a dictionary? The first is a verb, the second a noun.

Comment: @KateBunting Not always. ("The patient had many affects" and "she effected a plan.") Although in the case of the sentence in the question, the normal distinction applies.

Answer (score 0):

affect is a verb and effect is a noun in the sentence affect is the right word
for example, if you watch TV too much, it will affect your health

The rule comes in to effect next year
affect means to have an effect or influence on some thing

effect means force in the given example

However effect can also be used as a verb too
example, the architect has effected a number of changes in the plan.
here effect means bring about or cause

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence affect is the right answer ,because .affect is a verb and effect is a noun .

Effect is a change that somebody or something causes in a result,while affect is to make somebody sick or I'll.

If you want to know the different  the sentence does not sound the same for example the condition affects one in five weman.
The effect of heat on metal.

Comment: You might want to check the answers in the question that this is marked as a duplicate of.